# How to remove white spaces from columns in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, whitespace

I have an old SQL Server 2000 database from which I read data. My problem is every query involving a String returns a value the size of that column filled with blank spaces.

e.g: let's say we have a column called `NAME CHAR(20)`. All queries would return:

```
"John                    "
```

instead of just `"John"`.

Is there a configuration or parameter in my database that causes this, or anything at all that can be changed to avoid it? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I'd like to clarify, I'm reading my DB using JPA Repositories. I don't want to physically remove the whitespaces from the columns, or trim the values manually using RTRIM/LTRIM/REPLACE. I'm just trying to retrieve the column without trailing spaces, without adding any extra strain to the query or trimming the fields programatically.

Comment: Use `VARCHAR(20)` instead of `CHAR(20)` -  `char(n)` is *always* padded to the defined length with spaces (by definition)

Comment: have you considered a view or computed column ?

Comment: Yes I have. In fact, I'm currently reading from views. The problem is I'm not allowed to modify them in any way, for instance, to convert a char to varchar. I have to read the data as is. I was just wondering if there was any way to make it return the value without any trailing white spaces. Thanks anyway to both of you @marc_s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use REPLACE/RTRIM/LTRIM

```
select RTRIM(LTRIM(column_name)) from table_name
```

or

```
select  replace(column_name, ' ', '') from table_name
```

Comment: I have just added some more info on the subject. I wanted to avoid trimming the column both in the query and in the program that handles the String value. Thanks anyway!